# Pulling image from insecure registery with containerd

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd, insecure-connection

I have a problem when I pull images from insecure registries(in my case, it is harbor). I receive a connection refused error when I use the command below.

```
sudo crictl pull  192.168.12.10/calculator/app2:new
```

Below is the full error message:

```
DEBU[0000] get image connection                         
DEBU[0000] connect using endpoint 'unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock' with '2s' timeout 
DEBU[0000] connected successfully using endpoint: unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 
DEBU[0000] PullImageRequest: &PullImageRequest{Image:&ImageSpec{Image:192.168.12.10/calculator/app2:asdf,Annotations:map[string]string{},},Auth:nil,SandboxConfig:nil,} 
DEBU[0000] PullImageResponse: nil                       
FATA[0000] pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.12.10/calculator/app2:asdf": failed to resolve reference "192.168.12.10/calculator/app2:asdf": failed to do request: Head https://192.168.12.10/v2/calculator/app2/manifests/asdf: dial tcp 192.168.12.10:443: connect: connection refused
```

Added configuration to '/etc/containerd/config.toml' like this

```
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
      config_path = ""

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.auths]
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs]    
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."192.168.12.10:80".tls]
          insecure_skip_verify = true    
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.configs."192.168.12.10:80".auth]
          username = "admin12"
          password = "Hada123213"
          auth = "YWRtaW4xMjpIYWRhMTIzMjEzCg=="

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.headers]

      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."192.168.12.10:80"]
          endpoint = ["http://192.168.12.10:80"]
```

To configure this file, I use the below like on stack overflow and github:

[source one](https://rb.gy/o5axte)

[source two](https://rb.gy/ayzvck)

In my search on the web, more than 95 percent of websites said to add the insecure registry to /etc/docker/daemon.json to resolve this problem.

but its about docker not contaierd.

Answer (score 3):

Per https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/hosts.md

> The old CRI config pattern for specifying registry.mirrors and registry.configs has been DEPRECATED. You should now point your registry config_path to the path where your hosts.toml files are located.

The right way to setup should be (in my example `http://172.31.0.36` is the private insecure registry):

```bash
$ tree
.
├── certs.d
│   └── 172.31.0.36
│       └── hosts.toml
└── config.toml
```

where `config.toml` should include

```ini
version = 2

[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry]
   config_path = "/etc/containerd/certs.d"
```

and in `hosts.toml`:

```ini
server = "http://172.31.0.36"

[host."http://172.31.0.36"]
  skip_verify = true
```

Restart the `containerd` service:

```bash
$ sudo systemctl restart containerd
```

To confirm it works:

```bash
$ sudo crictl pull 172.31.0.36/newpathfly/hello-world
Image is up to date for sha256:feb5d9fea6a5e9606aa995e879d862b825965ba48de054caab5ef356dc6b3412
```

Answer (score 0):

in '/etc/containerd/config.toml' convert all of 192.168.12.10:80 to 192.168.12.10  so that will be working well.

because in your ctr command you refer to

```
sudo crictl pull  192.168.12.10/calculator/app2:new
```

and no refer to port number.

for more details look at this [link](https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-private).